# How to find length of embedded nested array in mongodb?

Tags: java, spring, web-services, hibernate, mongodb

How to find length of embedded nested array in mongodb? For example,
I have the below collection in my mongoDB. The loc field contains coordinates field which is an array and again it contains another array which is in 0th index. 
How can I find length of loc.corrdinates[0] ?
I tried to do this with using aggregation pipeline but it gives syntax error:

```
db.atolldata.aggregate([
                        {$project:{_id:0,
                                   fileName:1,
                         sizeOfArray:{$size:"$loc.coordinates[0]"}}}]);
```

.

Here is my collection

db.mydb.findOne();

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54ccb36fe4b0ff85abfee006"),
    "_class" : "com.inn.signaleye.model.AtollData",
    "rsrp" : "-124",
    "index" : 1,
    "rgb" : [
        192,
        157,
        0
    ],
    "loc" : {
        "type" : "Polygon",
        "coordinates" : [
            [
                [
                    91.5254213240325,
                    26.225096
                ],
                [
                    91.5254099392226,
                    26.225999
                ],
                [
                    91.52591034644685,
                    26.226004
                ],
                [
                    91.52592172739666,
                    26.225101
                ],
                [
                    91.5254213240325,
                    26.225096
                ]
            ]
        ]
    },
    "fileName" : "RSRP_ZOne46N_20m_SCFT.shp"
}
```

Comment: BatScream's answer is good, but are you actually trying to get the length of `coordinates` in a single document, or in all documents?  If the former, it may be easier to just get that document by ID and compute its length in your application.

Answer (score 3):

Make use of the [**$unwind**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) stage, to flatten the `coordinates` array, and then find the `size` in the `$project` stage.

```
db.atolldata.aggregate([
{$unwind:"$loc.coordinates"},
{$project:{"_id":0,"fileName":1,
           "sizeOfArray":{$size:"$loc.coordinates"}}}
])
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to create a field with the size of the array to work with it:

```
{$set : {arraySize: {$size: {$arrayElemAt : ['$loc.coordinates', 0]}}}}
```

Remember all documents have to include the loc field or the aggregation will fail (so you have to filter these documents first with $match).